# data source (from model) not loading in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, model-view-controller, uilabel

I have an `NSArray` filled of strings saved in a model (model.h and model.m), the array is filled with strings in a `TableViewController`, in which I can successful `edit` `save` and `access` the data from my model. I want to make the strings appear in an `UILabel` in a `ViewController` also, but it only shows (null), which means I'm not being successful in accessing the data from the model, someone could help?

PS: I'm not showing the code of the TableView cause thats working properly.

here is my Code:

**Model.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Model : NSObject<NSCoding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;



+(NSString *)getPathToArchive;
+(Model *)getModel;
+(void)saveModel:(Model *)aModel;


@end
```

**Model.m:**

```
#import "Model.h"

@implementation Model

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

+(NSString *)getPathToArchive {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"model.model"];
}

+(Model *)getModel{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[Model getPathToArchive]];
}

+(void)saveModel:(Model *)aModel {
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:aModel toFile:[Model getPathToArchive]];
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)anEncoder {
    [anEncoder encodeObject:self.model forKey:@"array"];


}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.model = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Model;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) Model *model;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Model.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [Model getModel];

   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 140, 40)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.model.array objectAtIndex:0] ];
    //index = 0 as example.
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Comment: where do you set `self.model` in `ViewController`? It seems it is `nil` in 'viewDidLoad`

Comment: where and how should I set self.model in ViewController? I thought [Model getModel] would do the job 'loading' the data from the model.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` change the following line:

```
    [Model getModel];
```

to

```
   self.model = [Mode getModel];
```

Your model does load the data in `getModel` method. But you still have to assign the `Model` instance returned by this method to the `model` property of your `ViewController`. Otherwise you won't be able to access the `Model`.